# How to get has_many objects in DataExtension object?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

SS4.4

I have two classes Member and Activity. A member has many activities. I have a class MemberExtension which extends Member. Inside MemberExtension, we have a has_many array containing ‘Activities’. How do we get the list of Activities in MemberExtension?

We have tried the following:

$this->Activities()

Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MemberExtension::Activities()

$this->getOwner()->Activities()

Error: Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Object->__call(): the method 'Activities' does not exist on 'SilverStripe\Security\Member'

We also ran dev/build?flush

```
// MemberExtension class
class MemberExtension extends DataExtension {
    public static $has_many = [
        'Activities' => Activity::class
    ];
}

// Activity class
class Activity extends DataObject {
    private static $has_one = [
        'Member' => Member::class,
    ];
}

// Register MemberExtension in _config.php
Member::add_extension(MemberExtension::class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the MemberExtension `$this->owner->Activities()` should work.

In Silverstripe CMS 4 you also need to use the FQCN (fully qualified class name, aka including the whole namespace. This means you need to use `SilverStripe\Security\Member` when adding the extension. It's also a good practice to use yml config files for adding extensions to classes, see [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/extending/extensions/#extensions-and-dataextensions).

```
SilverStripe\Security\Member:
  extensions:
    - MemberExtension
```

assuming your extension doesn't have a namespace yet.

Then after running dev/build/flush you should be able to call the Activities relation as shown above:

```
$activities = $this->owner->Activities(); //name of the relation as always
```